# How do I get 3rd dimensional array from a 4th-d array in python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array

I got this array which size is (26,16,16,16).
I need to plot the last 3 dimensions vs  different parameters but it is not clear to me how do I cut the 1rst dimension without making a disaster in order to get just the (16,16,16) data values
Sorry if this is kinda easy. I am new into python and still learning a lot of basic stuff.

Answer (score 1):

You can access the properties by using first index like **ARRAY[0], ARRAY[1], ARRAY[2] ...** You can access all the 26 Properties this way and plot them.

Comment: The array is storing different property values in shape (16, 16, 16). You can read it in question. Hence, In context of the question the elements of the array are properties, also  they cannot be called slices as we are accessing with single index, not a range of indexes.

Answer (score 0):

The question is *which* of the 16x16x16 values you need. A two dimensional array is just a matrix, so now consider a three dimensional one. An array of dimensions (4, 3, 3) is just four 3x3 matrices in one data-object. So if you type `array[0]` you get the first 3x3, `array[1]` the second and so on.

Your 4 dimensional array now is basically 26 blocks of matrices, each block 16 matrices deep and each matrix 16x16. So if you want to access just the first block, `array[0]` returns that. If you now want the third matrix of the first block, go  `array[0][2]` and so on.

Answer (score 0):

A 16x16 matrix is just a vector that has 16 lines with rows of size 16.

A 26x16x16x16 matrix is just a vector that has 16x16x16, 26 times. You can do it by doing like this, for instance:

```
dimension_1 = matrix[0:1, 16, 16, 16]
dimension_2 = matrix[1:2, 16, 16, 16]
dimension_3 = matrix[2:3, 16, 16, 16]
```

If you just want the entire column for a specific row, you can also do:

```
dimension_1 = matrix[0, :, :, :]
dimension_2 = matrix[1, :, :, :]
dimension_3 = matrix[2, :, :, :]
```

Where [a:b] represents slices, where a is the initial value you'd like to crop your column and b is the value where the crop ends.

Assuming that by the last 3 dimensions you mean to say the indices 24, 25, 26

For a more concrete example:

```
random_matrix = np.random.rand(26, 16, 16, 16)
```

Now, we have a huge matrix, to select any given index

```
test =  random_matrix[0, :, :, :].reshape(16, 16, 16)
```

Or alternative way:

```
test_2 = random_matrix[0, 0:16, 0:16, 0:16]
```

Selecting the last three elements:

```
test_3 = random_matrix[23:26, :, : ,:]
```

Comment: Have you tried running any of this?

Comment: I was going by head, but now i fixed it.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it was really useful to me.

Comment: You can accept my answer and/or upvote it, if you think it was really really helpful